# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Im Creating an app step by step using this tutorial : [google map api v2](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw)

But I'm getting Error ! I already tried and read many answer to resolve the error! But I can't resolve it

Logcat :

```
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249): Process: com.example.finalymapapi, PID: 2249
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.finalymapapi/com.example.finalymapapi.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.example.finalymapapi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     ... 11 more
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4452000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.t(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.B(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.u.A(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.ip(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:290)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
12-10 10:30:02.975: E/AndroidRuntime(2249):     ... 20 more
```

- Im get SHA1 from eclipse->Window->Preferences->android->Build
  [image]
  and my Manifist file :

> 

```
    <permission
         android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
         android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission  android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.finalymapapi.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
       android:value="AIzaSyAHkTtRSWMcC-mUz9jH9CBlrxoeV2Qon7c"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and my activity file :

[image]

My javafile :

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think you should use mapfragment in place of fragment

Comment: read this :https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

Comment: @user3787191 have you tried my way?

Comment: yes Im add meta-data and check Google api ! Its work

Comment: شما ایرانی هستید ؟ بابا خب میگفتید اینقدر خودمو نمیکشتم به زود با گوگل ترنسلیت ترجمه کردم اینارو :))

Comment: @user3787191 nice to meet you refigh :D (would u like to join [us](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54844/persian-chat) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add  `<meta-data>` tag in `<application>` tag in your `manifest.xml`

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

---

if still crashes then check:

Use the mapFragment element as below in the `xml`

```
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lineartab" />
```

You need to check the project properties:

1. Does `Google API's` selected?
2. Google play service lib project added?

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the exception add the following line to `<application>` in you `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```